# Animation with Trail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to make an animation that leaves a trail behind it for the iPhone. Any ideas how to do that?

THank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CAEmitterLayers to do particle effects. iOS 5 only though.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The Cocoa Touch framework does not have any in-built features that let you do this, that I know of.
If you want to make one yourself, you would have to construct the animation frame-by-frame. Each frame would be a snapshot of what the screen would look like at that point in the animation. They can displayed one after the other with `UIImageView`.

```
NSArray *frames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frame1, frame2,...., nil];
UIImageView *animateFrames = [UIImageView alloc] init];
animateFrames.animationImages = frames;
animateFrames.animationDuration = DESIRED_DURATION;
animateFrames.repeatCount = 1;

[animateFrames startAnimating];
```

Comment: I have a feeling something like that would look choppy. Any ideas how to add a gradient or something to the frames?

Comment: It depends on the number of frames. The more frames, the less choppy - at the cost of a higher memory footprint.